# Would there be any consequence such as app crash on Firebase old API calls?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Would there be any consequence such as app crash on Firebase old API calls, if I don't migrate my app from Firebase Crash reporting to Crashlytics?

I am facing an issue regarding some of the user data not being retained in Shared Preferences when I update my app from an old version using Firebase crash reporting to a new version with Firebase Crashytics integrated into it. While the above might be a run-time bug from my side (though previous app version updates never caused this issue), this brings me to my question of whether my app would crash on the Firebase old API calls, if I choose to not upgrade to Crashlytics, till I resolve the above issue.

Are there any bad consequences for my app, apart from the obvious part that I would not receive crash reports?

Answer (score 1):

You app may continue to try to send crash reports, causing your users extra data usage when trying to send those reports, and extra file storage to persist those reports for as long as the SDK attempts to retry sending the reports.  I don't expect your app will crash.

Comment: I guess I will comment out all the firebase calls for now, and release an update then.